# Switch with UInt16 value and case with int in swift 3

Tags: switch-statement, swift3

I need to convert my project to swift 3.
I have a switch like this:

```
switch self.setupMan?.typeRegulation.value {
        case 0: //
            self.mainRegulationSetValue.text = String(Double(self.runtime.setPoint)/10)
            break
        case UInt16(1): //Giri motore
            self.mainRegulationSetValue.text = String(self.runtime.setPoint)
            break
        case 2: //Portata
            self.mainRegulationSetValue.text = String(Double(self.runtime.mch)/10)
            break
        default:
            break
        }
```

self.setupMan?.typeRegulation.value is a UInt16 var; Xcode get me this error:

```
Expression pattern of type 'Int' cannot match values of type 'Uint16?'
```

I tried to cast like this:

```
case UINt16(0):
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: `value` is supposed to have **one** single type, just write `case 1:`

Comment: It's a test I made. I get an error even if I write case 1:

Comment: What error do you get? The error message reveals that `value` is `Int`

Comment: Expression pattern of type 'Int' cannot match values of type 'Uint16?'

Comment: It's impossible that you get the error with `case 1:`, once again according the error message `typeRegulation.value` is `Int`

Comment: typeRegulation.value is UInt16; I tried to cast typeRegulation.value to Int and I get no error, so I solved. Thanks anyway